# How clear internal delimiter between two external delimiter

Tags: php, regex, string

what regular expression i can use for match two or more delimitator internal a two delimitator and clear it? Some example:

```
1) input:  %word1 %word2%%   then output:  %word1 word2%
2) input:  %word1 %word2% %word3%%% then output: %word1 word2 word3%
3) input:  %%word1 word2% word3% then output: %word1 word2 word3%
```

and so on.
Or apply a replace ignoring a substring from two delimiter, for example having:

```
%word1 word2% text word2
```

replacing word2 with %word2% without apply it to %word1 word2% having so as output something as:

```
%word1 word2% text %word2%
```

and not:

```
%word1 %word2%% text %word2%
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of the question:

```
$ cat a.php
<?php
   echo preg_replace('/(?<!%)(word2)(?!%)/', '%word2%', '%word2% %word1 word2% text word2');
?>
$ php a.php
%word2% %word1 word2% text %word2%
```

The regex works like this:

```
(?<!%)(word2)(?!%)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KNuhf4gIRQtKW850)

Comment: can i ask you to check about code which i have posted now? Passing to regular expression a PHP-variable it not work. Thanks again.

Comment: This regex:  (?<!%)(word2)(?!%)  match too a substring of a word. How i can fix it? For example  if i have "word" and "ord" it consider "ord" inside "word" as valid and this is a error.

Comment: @MarcelloImpastato Maybe you could make use of word boundaries. Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I have tried writing: (\W?<!%)(word2)(\W?!%) and work but clear spaces and dot (if next to word matched". For example if i want match "home" and "Milan" and my phrase is : " My home is to Milan." it return me something as: "Myhomeis to Milan". From a side i solve for word but from other side make other problem :(

Comment: @MarcelloImpastato Did you read about `\b` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would be helpful or not but I have a simple solution:

```
$string = "%%word1 word2% word3%";
$output = "%".str_replace("%", "", $string)."%";
```

It will not work if your word contains '%' in between.

Comment: Hello, this solution not work if input string is a substring of other string. And should to have effect only inside two delimiter without clear external delimiter. If input string is %word% not should return word.

Comment: It will return %word% if input string is %word%

Comment: If i have this string: " %word1 word2% word3 word4 word2 " replacing word2 with %word2% i need get: " %word1 word2% word3 word4 %word2% " and not: " %word1 %word2%% word3 word4 %word2% ". Your solution return me: " % word1 word2 word3 word4 word2 % " and so not ok, understand?

Answer (score 0):

Taking example from @Nehal, i have now this two portion of code:

```
// CODE 1
// string return: "word1 word2 word3 word4 word2" <-- failed
$string = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word2";
$array = array("word1 word2", "word2");
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $string = preg_replace('/(?<!%)($value)(?!%)/', '%$value%', $string);
}
echo $string;

// CODE 2
//string2 return: "%word1 word2% word3 word4 %word2%" <-- correct
$string0 = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word2";
$string1 = preg_replace('/(?<!%)(word1 word2)(?!%)/', '%word1 word2%', $string0);
$string2 = preg_replace('/(?<!%)(word2)(?!%)/', '%word2%', $string1);
echo $string2;
```

CODE1 fail but CODE2 work fine! As i can fix CODE1 ? I suppose which problem is value in regular expression passed for variable. Some solution? Thanks again.

***UPDATE:***
Solved replacing:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<!%)($value)(?!%)/', '%$value%', $string);
```

with:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<!%)('.$value.')(?!%)/', '%'.$value.'%', $string);
```